# Inference on several inputs in order to calculate the loss function

Tags: tensorflow

I am modeling a perceptual process in tensorflow. In the setup I am interested in, the modeled agent is playing a resource game: it has to choose 1 out of *n* resouces, by relying only on the label that a classifier gives to the resource. Each resource is an ordered pair of two reals. The classifier only sees the first real, but payoffs depend on the second. There is a function taking first to second.

Anyway, ideally I'd like to train the classifier in the following way:

1. In each run, the classifier give labels to *n* resources.
2. The agent then gets the payoff of the resource corresponding to the highest label in some predetermined ranking (say, A >  B > C > D), and randomly in case of draw.
3. The loss is taken to be the normalized absolute difference between the payoff thus obtained and the maximum payoff in the set of resources. I.e., (Payoff_max - Payoff) / Payoff_max

For this to work, one needs to run inference *n* times, once for each resource, before calculating the loss. Is there a way to do this in tensorflow? If I am tackling the problem in the wrong way feel free to say so, too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much knowledge in ML aspects of this, but from programming point of view, I can see doing it in two ways. One is by copying your model *n* times. All the copies can [share the same variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope). The output of all of these copies would go into some function that determines the *the highest label*. As long as this function is differentiable, variables are shared, and *n* is not too large, it should work. You would need to feed all *n* inputs together. Note that, backprop will run through each copy and update your weights *n* times. This is generally not a problem, but if it is, I heart about some fancy tricks one can do by using partial_run.

Another way is to use tf.while_loop. It is pretty clever - it stores activations from each run of the loop and can do backprop through them. The only tricky part should be to accumulate the inference results before feeding them to your loss. Take a look at TensorArray for this. This question can be helpful: [Using TensorArrays in the context of a while_loop to accumulate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822097/using-tensorarrays-in-the-context-of-a-while-loop-to-accumulate-values)